# eBuildfire: Notifications issue

Tags: mobile, notifications, buildfire

I have created an app that uses push notifications to notify people about important events during their day. For a regular user, the app can create anywhere between 120 to 350 notifications every 7 days (we create all the notifications for the upcoming week). In some cases when users change their accounts, we are renewing the notification by canceling them and creating them again. This can happen 2 to 4 times in a span of a few minutes.

We had situations when the app users reported OLD notifications still being sent when those should have been canceled.

We tested this multiple times while adding logs for each notification that got canceled or added - and each time this worked ok - the logs matched the total we were expecting.

Is there a limitation to the number of notifications that can be canceled or added at one single time by the APP? Is there something that could break the requests?

Is there a way to see if the notifications got created or not, other than checking the response of the requests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing this in a plugin or BuildFire Gateway (public api) server to server?

Comment: This is done inside/by a custom buildifre plugin.

Comment: Are you waiting for the callback on the cancelation API to make sure they in fact got canceled?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above while testing all the responses we get are successful. Could there be situations when these are not successful?